# appending an array to a csv line using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I have a function which i am using to scrape a list of thumbnails from my blog.

```
function scrapeThumbs($title,$link){


    $html = file_get_html($link);


        $arrayImg= array();

        foreach($html->find('.ad-thumb-list') as $item1)
        {

            foreach($item1->find('a') as $image)
            $imgP= $image->href;
            array_push($arrayImg, $imgP);


        }

        //write on csv file
        $fp = fopen('products.csv', 'a') or die("Can't open file");

        $list =array(array ($title,$arrayImg));

        foreach ($list as $fields) {
            fputcsv($fp, $fields);
        }

        fclose($fp);

        // clean up memory
        $html->clear();
        unset($html);

}
```

When the csv file is generated, i do have the title exactly how i want. But instead of having an array with thumbnail urls - in the csv i have "array". what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your `$list` is a multi dimensional array;

Try something like this : `fputcsv($fp, $fields[0]);`, see below code.

$list =array(array ($title,$arrayImg));

```
    foreach ($list as $fields) {
        fputcsv($fp, $fields[0]);
    }
```

to see the structure of the array use `print_r($list);`

Answer (score 0):

You are not creating `$list` in the right fotmat. `$arrayImg` is already an array so the correct format would be this:

```
$list =array(array($title),$arrayImg);
```